# Can the name of the class.tupleof() items be retrieved?

Tags: types, tuples, d

When looping in the result of **AnObject.tupleof**, I can get the *size* or the *value* as a string but can I get more advanced infos over the tuple items (edit) and particularly the original data name (as written in the source class)? The background idea would be to use this property as a kind of *RTTI*.

Comment: What kind of information do you need?
You can use std.traits.FieldTypeTuple template for a static array that you can loop over using foreach.

Comment: I'd need the orginal data name

Comment: Do you, by "original data name", mean the actually variable/object name? And you want to obtain "AnObject" string in the OT's case?

Comment: Yes I meant the original name juste like the prop .stringof ... but actually I've adopted another strategy for solving the programming problem encountered, so it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tupleof` returns **value tuple** which is not enough to get field names. Also there is not such thing as "data name", as D does not have any relation between data (== values) and field names, it exists only other way around.

Some of built-in traits may help though:

```
module test;

class Experiment
{
    class Nested
    {
    }

    Nested nested;
    int plain;
    void delegate() skipped;
}

import std.traits : isCallable, fullyQualifiedName;
import std.typetuple : Filter;

template allFields(alias T)
{
    private template combinedFilter(string name)
    {
        // filter out nested type definitions and methods
        // side effect: will filter out delegate/function pointer fields, don't know if listing those makes sense
        mixin("alias field = " ~ fullyQualifiedName!T ~ "." ~ name ~ ";"); 
        enum combinedFilter = !is(field) && !isCallable!field;
    }

    alias allFields = Filter!(combinedFilter, __traits(allMembers, T));
}

void main()
{   
    pragma(msg, allFields!Experiment);
}
```

You can experiment with this code on the fly with this [DPaste](http://dpaste.1azy.net/652d19de).

Probably there is a more simple solution, but given your question wording, most generic approach and small sample of D static introspection power may be of better use.

Hope I have understood the question right this time.

Comment: There was an error in my question, the problem encountered was also about retrieving the name of each element, as written in the Experiment class, so *a* and *NestedBase*. Otherwise your answer 'd be valid. elem.stringof returns elem...